# Retrieving mosek error code from solver in cvxpy

Tags: error-code, cvxpy, mosek

Using mosek in cvxpy, I'm getting the error that the solver failed. Is there a way to recover the error code from Mosek? Cvxpy doesn't seem to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Cvxpy ignores it. However, you can hack it by changing the line in `mosek_coinf.py` that does `task.optimize` and retrieving the response code according to https://docs.mosek.com/8.1/pythonapi/optimizer-task.html#mosek.task.optimize

Moreover, if you enable logging (`verbose=True`) then you should see from the solver log what happened.